# array_replace throwing php_warning but working anyway

Tags: terms

Hello I have a question which is maybe more PHP question than WordPress, but could be interesting in a WordPress context in case someone wants to add properties to an WP object.

I have created a custom taxonomy and I'm using an option to add order to each terms.

To get that order in my theme, i use those two functions : the first one retrieve the terms, and then they get ordered :

```
    // SORT BY ORDER 
    function cmp( $a, $b ) { 
        if(  $a->order ==  $b->order ){ return 0 ; } 
        return ($a->order < $b->order ) ? -1 : 1;
    } 

    // FUNCTION TO INJECT ORDER ITEM IN TERM OBJECT
    function inject_order( $term_objects ) {
        if ( $term_objects ) {
            foreach ( $term_objects as $term_object ) {
                $term_id = $term_object->term_id;
                $term_order  = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$term_id" )['tax_order_nb'];
                $term_object->order = $term_order;
                array_replace( $term_objects, $term_object );
            }
            return $term_objects;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // FUNCTION TO GET CHILDREN TERMS AND ORDER THEM
    function get_children_and_order_terms( $term_id = '0' ) {
        $term_children = get_terms( 'category_effectif', array( 'parent' => $term_id, 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
        if ( $term_children ) {
            $term_children = inject_order( $term_children ); 
            usort ( $term_children, 'cmp' );
            return $term_children;
        }
    }
```

It's working perfectly, but I have a PHP_Warning `array_replace(): Argument #2 is not an array`

I would like to correct that error and make it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$term_object->order` tells you `$term_object` is an object. [`array_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) expects an array, not an object.

Not sure why it works, maybe PHP is casting the object to an array.

```
array_replace( $term_objects, (array) $term_object );
```

… could fix the warning.

Comment: Works like a charm ! I checked before posting code to transform an object to an array but it was somehow complicated. Your solution works perfectly : order is still injected, without warning now. Thanks.

Comment: There are a number of places in WordPress where a function or method claims it takes either an array or an object, but actually does *both* at different times, depending on what calls it. Could be this is the result of one of those.

Comment: @ChrisKrycho True, but `array_replace()` is a built-in PHP function.

Comment: Of course you're correct. I had misread the original question; I thought he was dealing with something other than he actually was. That'll teach me to read more carefully.